# Image Texture not working

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

[image]Hi everyone i dont know why my image Textures arent working 
i tried to us this image texture
https://www.cgbookcase.com/textures/scratched-gold-01?source=textures.one

but it does not show up in any kind.
Besides from that i dont understand why my object is looking like plastic maybe someone can help me and give some tipps.
Thank you already

[image]

Comment: Have you modified your material to include the textures? Can you add a screenshot of your material nodes?

Comment: sure. what do you mean with modifying my material?

Comment: I meant that you've created a material that uses the textures (which you did). Have you switched to *LookDev* or *Rendered* viewport mode? *Solid* mode doesn't display any textures. Or does your material not show up in the rendered image (F12)? Then you probably haven't assigned the material to the  object.

Comment: the material shows up just not as displayed it looks simply golden

Comment: You mean it doesn't look like the preview on the website? It probably makes sense to add a texture coordinate node as well as a mapping node to your material. The scale for size of your texture might be off. Also make sure that you have proper lighting and something to reflect otherwise metal will look unrealistic (e.g. use an HDRI).

Comment: where should i add these 2 notes. Sorry im at the very beginning xD

Comment: Did you move the blend file or the images separately?